# When is the identity of User assigned when invoking a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, claims-based-identity

I'm invoking a method in my controller and hit a breakpoint in its constructor. Checking *User.Claims.First(...)* throws an exception and after a closer investigation, it turns out that *User* is *null*.

It makes sense, since the controller can't know who's the anonymous user invoking it. Then I add the header *Authorization* valuing it by *Bearer xxx.yyy.zzz* (Postman as well as my Angular application). The token is correct because tampering with it causes the status code *401 Unauthorized*.

So, I'm concluding that the security setup works, the policy is behaving as supposed to (invoking with a token corresponding to a user who lacks the privileges to said action is not executed).

Pasting the token text to *jwt.io* gives the expected details on the claims. Hence, I'm concluding that the token should be readable and parsable to the application's libraries.

So the question is this. **How's the *User* instantiated (when, where, based on what) for the controller?** Alternatively, how to google it (I've tried for a while but I realize that I'm fumbling in the dark barking up a random tree).

The token is equipped with claims in the following way.

```
Claim[] claims =
{
  new Claim(ClaimTypes.Expiration, TokenExpiration.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.DateTime),
  new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName, ClaimValueTypes.String),
  new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, member.Privilege + "", ClaimValueTypes.Integer),
  new Claim(ClaimTypes.Version, "0.1", ClaimValueTypes.String),
  new Claim(ClaimTypes.Webpage, "xxx.azurewebsites.net", ClaimValueTypes.String),
  new Claim("NetworkId", member.Network.Id.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String),
  new Claim("MemberId", member.Id.ToString(), ClaimValueTypes.String),
  new Claim("Author", "yyy", ClaimValueTypes.String)
};
SymmetricSecurityKey key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(SecurityKey);
SigningCredentials credentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(
  "xxx.azurewebsites.net",
  "xxx.azurewebsites.net",
  claims,
  DateTime.UtcNow,
  TokenExpiration,
  credentials);
string output = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
```

**edit** The *Startup* is set as follows.

```
services.AddSingleton<IUtilityService, UtilityService>();
services.AddSingleton<IEmailService, EmailService>();
services.AddCors(_ => _.AddPolicy("Open policy", __ => __
  .AllowAnyOrigin()
  .AllowAnyHeader()
  .AllowAnyMethod()));
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddJwtBearer(_ =>
  {
    _.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
      ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
      ValidateAudience = false,
      ValidateIssuer = false,
      ValidateActor = true,
      ValidateLifetime = true,
      IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey( ... )
    };
  });
  services.AddAuthorization(_ => _.AddPolicy("Common", __ => ... ));
  services.AddAuthorization(_ => _.AddPolicy("Super", __ => ... ));
  services.AddAuthorization(_ => _.AddPolicy("Admin", __ => ... ));
  services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(_ => ...);
  services.AddSwaggerGen(_ => ... );
  services.AddDbContext<Context>(_ => _.UseSqlServer( ... ));
```

**edit again** The *Configure* is set as follows.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

  app.Use(async (context, next) =>
  {
    try { await next(); }
    catch (Exception) { context.Response.StatusCode = ... }
  });

  app.UseCors("Open policy");
  app.UseAuthentication();
  app.UseMvc();
  app.UseSwagger();
  app.UseSwaggerUI(...);
}
```

Comment: The user principle is set in the authentication middleware.  For the cookie middleware, this happens in `CookieAuthenticationHandler.AuthenticateCoreAsync`.

Comment: If you share your startup code that would be useful.  The order of middleware is also important.

Comment: @MarkG Sorry to have omitted that. It's kind of obvious now that you mentioned it. However, I didn't realize it until now. Plese see the edit in a minute.

Comment: @Amy I've updated the question with my *Startup*. I can see where authentication and authorization takes place. However, I'm not clear which of the steps corresponds to the invokation of the controller's constructor. Please advise. (Also, I'm not using cookies but JWTokens, if that's of any significance.)

Comment: @DonkeyBanana What you're asking about is the Web API pipeline: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/888/aspnet-webapi-message-lifecycle

Comment: Cookies vs JWT isn't significant.  Open up the source (using ILSpy, for instance) for the JWT middleware, locate where it registers its own `AuthenticationHandler<T>`.  They're structured the same way.  I only brought up cookies because its what I had available.

Comment: Take a look at [JwtBearerHandler](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/a2cb92b358daf7552294060cd947d85afcc07049/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/JwtBearerHandler.cs) class.

Comment: For ASP.NET Core Web API the pipeline is different from the Web API 2 version. I haven't found an equivalent diagram as the [Microsoft Web API poster](https://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf) but [this post describes in good detail how the Core pipeline is designed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by analysing the event pipe (as mentioned by @amy) and noticed that the action invokation is preceded by *OnActionExecuting* method ([shown in the PDF](https://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf) courtesy of @sixtosaez).

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
  Claim claim = User.Claims
    .First(_ => _.Type == "MemberId");
  ...
}
```

I'd imagine that it's also possible to get working by altering the registration order of middleware in *Start* (as mentioned by @MarkG) but I don't feel confident in playing around with that due to noobness and confusion.

Comment: What do you mean by altering the _registration order of middleware_?  There's no harm in playing around with this stuff...it's the best way to learn.

Comment: @Brad If you check the comments to the question, you'll see MarkG stating that the order of middleware being registered does affect how the execution order behaves. Since I'm summarizing what others said, I wanted to bring in that piece of info too. However, since I haven't tried it, I can't vouch that it does resolve my issue.

Comment: @Brad By no means I'm implying that it's harmful to play around with the order of registrations if one's to learn. I haven't had time, though, and the other hints actually resolved my problem. I went with it and chose not to tamper with the middleware because I'm afraid that I'd create damages to something else in my application. If you feel that you can provide a suggestion on the middleware's order based solution to the original question, feel welcome and urged to post it, though.

Comment: You actually haven't shown the order of middleware registration.  Middleware is typically registered in the `Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)` method with `app.UseXXX(...);` statements and order is very important.  You have only shown your service registrations `services.AddXXX(...);` which don't affect the request pipeline and order is not always important depending on the services your registering (some services can throw exceptions if other services are not registered before the `IServiceProvider` is built).

Comment: @Brad So stupid... Of course, you're right. I got confused by all the stuff and forgot to post it in the end. Have a peek at the updated question, please.